# flex-sm analog in angular material2 application

Tags: angular, angular-material, angularjs-material

This is code which works with angularjs material.

```html
<div flex="50" flex-sm="100">
    Some data
</div>
```

How can I implement it in my Angular material 2 app?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Follow these steps to get it working:

1. Install the `flex-layout` dependency:

   ```bash
   npm install @angular/flex-layout
   ```
2. Import the `FlexLayoutModule` to your `AppModule`:

   ```ts
   import { FlexLayoutModule } from '@angular/flex-layout';
   import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';

   @NgModule({
       imports: [
           FlexLayoutModule,
           // Other modules
       ]
   })
   export class AppModule {}
   ```
3. Change your code to the following:

   ```html
   <div fxFlex="50%" fxFlex.sm="100%">
       Some data
   </div>
   ```

   - [Flex layout demo website](https://tburleson-layouts-demos.firebaseapp.com/#/responsive)